# Rounding small floating point numbers

Tags: r, rounding

Suppose I have a numeric vector which I'd like to round to 'prettier' numbers, such as:

```
vec <- c(1.739362e-08,8.782537e-08,0.5339712)
```

I'd like it to be:

```
pretty.vec <- c(1.74e-08,8.78e-08,0.53)
```

How do I achieve that? using `round` doesn't really help since it rounds the first two elements to 0:

```
> round(vec,2)
[1] 0.00 0.00 0.53
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about `?signif` ?  (Depending on your application you  could also use `print(...,digits=3)`)

```
vec <- c(1.739362e-08,8.782537e-08,0.5339712)
signif(vec,digits=3)
## [1] 1.74e-08 8.78e-08 5.34e-01
print(vec,digits=3)
## [1] 1.74e-08 8.78e-08 5.34e-01
```

It's fairly hard to get R to format the elements of a vector differently from each other: usually it assumes you want that consistency.

```
print(sprintf("%1.3g",vec),quote=FALSE)
## [1] 1.74e-08 8.78e-08 0.534
```

Also related: `?format`, `?options` (see "scipen")